# Getting error when trying to send api requests to aws api gateway

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to connect my android studio app to aws api gatway and keep getting this error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.project.pathrighted, PID: 28837
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException:  (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.invoke(ApiClientHandler.java:118)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
at $Proxy2.connectionsPost(Unknown Source)
at com.project.pathrighted.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:28)
at com.project.pathrighted.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$vYa8elHDb_v9l_re9vSYQmIBQdw(Unknown Source:0)
at com.project.pathrighted.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7503)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7480)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:813)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28445)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7945)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:603)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1605)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseMessage(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:110)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.createHttpResponse(UrlHttpClient.java:92)
at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:85)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.invoke(ApiClientHandler.java:109)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006) 
at $Proxy2.connectionsPost(Unknown Source) 
at com.project.pathrighted.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:28) 
at com.project.pathrighted.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$vYa8elHDb_v9l_re9vSYQmIBQdw(Unknown Source:0) 
at com.project.pathrighted.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7503) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7480) 
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:813) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28445) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7945) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:603) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

This is my current code:

```
package com.project.pathrighted

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientFactory
import com.project.clientsdk.PathrightedClient

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val myButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.anonymousProButton)

    // Initialize the API client factory
    val factory = ApiClientFactory()

    // Create the API client for the "users" resource
    val usersApiClient = factory.build(PathrightedClient::class.java)

    myButton.setOnClickListener {
        // Code to be executed when the button is clicked

        // For example, show a toast message or perform some action
        // when the button is clicked.
        usersApiClient.connectionsPost()
        showToast("Button Clicked!")
    }



  }

private fun showToast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

}
```

Comment: the best way to debug is enable logging at gateway, if possible share it for more info!!!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MrOverflow how would I enable logging? Sorry I am new to using AWS services.

Comment: @PhoenixDeVentures kindly refer following link. https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs